# React State Not Updating on First click and Component Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, setstate

`retrieveInTransit()` is the click handler. An API call retrieves data and returns an array of objects into the new state object in the `setState()` function. The first click logs an empty array for the `pumps` property. If I click it again, I get the populated array of `pumps`. Why do I have to click twice? The `Equipment component` does not render even though the log in the `render()` function returns the correct array of pumps which is passed in as a prop for the `Equipment component`. I am at a loss on this and any help would be appreciated.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {ListGroup} from 'reactstrap';
import Equipment from './Equipment';

class Transit extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pending: false,
      pumps: []
    };
  }

  handleCancelClick = (index) => {
    this.setState((prevState) =>
      prevState.pumps[index].isCancelled = !prevState.pumps[index].isCancelled
    );

    this.setState((prevState) => {
        prevState.pumps.every((equipment) => equipment.isCancelled === false)
          ? prevState.pending = false: prevState.pending = true
      }
    )};


  populate_transit = () => {
    let pumpArray = [];
    fetch('http://192.168.86.26:8000/api/v1/transit_list', {mode: 'cors'})
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(MyJson => MyJson.map((entry) =>{
        if (document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(entry.transferfrom)) {
          pumpArray.push(
            {
              unitnumber: entry.unitnumber,
              id: entry.id,
              message: entry.unitnumber + ' was moved to ' + entry.transferto,
              isCancelled: false
            });
        }}));

    return pumpArray
  };


  cancelTransit = () => {
    let cancelled = this.state.pumps.filter((movement) => movement.isCancelled);
    let cancelledId = cancelled.map((object) => object.id);
    fetch('http://192.168.86.26:8000/api/v1/transit_list/', {
      method:'POST',
      mode: 'cors',
      body: JSON.stringify(cancelledId),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
        }
      );
    this.populate_transit()
  };

  retrieveInTransit = () => {
    if (this.state.pending) {
      this.setState({
        pending: false,
        pumps: this.cancelTransit()
      }, console.log(this.state))} else {
      this.setState({
        pending: false,
        pumps: this.populate_transit()
      }, console.log(this.state))
    }

  };


  render() {
    console.log(this.state.pumps);
    return (
      <ListGroup>
        <Equipment transitequipment={this.state.pumps} cancelClick={this.handleCancelClick}/>
        <button className='btn btn-dark' onClick={this.retrieveInTransit}>
          {this.state.pending ? 'Submit Cancellations': 'Refresh'}
        </button>
      </ListGroup>
    );
  }
}

export default  Transit;
```

Comment: the second argument of setState needs a function, you pass it the result of console.log(this.state) (your log gets executed right away and not "after" the state changed)

Comment: @K.. but everytime `setState` is called, a re-render occurs, and in that case, the `console.log` in the render method should log the updated state, right?

Comment: you would have to use () => console.log(this.state) otherwise it would be executes right before you call setState

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 populate_transit = () => {
let pumpArray = [];
fetch('http://192.168.86.26:8000/api/v1/transit_list', {mode: 'cors'})
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(MyJson => MyJson.map((entry) =>{
    if (document.getElementsByClassName('title')[0].innerText.toLowerCase().includes(entry.transferfrom)) {
      pumpArray.push(
        {
          unitnumber: entry.unitnumber,
          id: entry.id,
          message: entry.unitnumber + ' was moved to ' + entry.transferto,
          isCancelled: false
        });
    }}));

return pumpArray};
```

So, In the code above, you are returning `pumpArray` outside of the `fetch` call. Since `fetch` takes time to `call` the `api` and `resolve` the promise, the current value of your `pumpArray` = `[]` that's why you get the empty array at first. On the `next click` `promise` is already `resolved` so you get your `pumpedArray`.
In order to fix this, move the `pumpArray` inside `then`.

Comment: Man! Sharp eyes :D

Comment: Thanks. This makes sense. I restructured so that I am now returning the pumpArray from within the .then(). Now I am dealing with the state.pumps being undefined after setting the state.

Comment: Can you not return a value from withing .then()?

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with calling a function within the object passed to setState?

Comment: Yeah, instead of passing the function, use `this.setState` inside the `then`

Comment: Heck ya. Thanks all. I was trying to setState using something that didn't exist yet.

Comment: If my answer helped solve your problem please mark it the best answer. Thanks.

Comment: I know this is old now but I wanted to add here for others in the future.  I've been trying to get my head around React state for a while now, and one thing that helped me a lot is to make sure I keep form submits/api calls separate from setting state.

When I am setting state from a textbox for example I will set it from the onBlur of the textbox itself,  so that when Submit or any API calls happen, state is available to those methods.

Comment: @SC1988 You don't really need to do that. All you need is to know that if you are doing an async action then just wait for the async action to finish before using it, either as state or anything else.